# How to re-sort a list/text with Python?

Tags: python, split

My bot reads another bot's message, then temporarily saves that message, makes a few changes with `.replace` and then the bot is supposed to change the format of the entries it finds.

I have tried quite a few things, but have not figured it out.

**The text looks like this:**

```py
06 6 452872995438985XXX
09 22 160462182344032XXX
11 17 302885091519234XXX
```

**And I want to get the following format:**

```py
6/06 452872995438985XXX
22/09 160462182344032XXX
17/11 302885091519234XXX
```

**I have already tried the following things:**

```py
splitsprint = test.split(' ') # test is in this case the string we use e.g. the text shown above

        for x in splitsprint:
            month, day, misc = x
            print(f"{day}/{month} {misc}")
---
newline = test.split('\n')

        for line in newline:
            month, day, misc = line.split(' ')
            print(f"{day}/{month} {misc}")
```

But always I got a `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)` error or similar.

Does anyone here see my error?

Comment: I sugget adding `print(x)` and `print(line)` at the beginning of the respective `for` loops to see what it contains on each iteration. Note that you can do `for month, day, misc in splitsprint` directly in the for loop instead of unpacking `x` later.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with the provided text. Maybe there's a trailing space in your local text.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice `newline = test.split('\n')` and then printing `line` actually has what I am looking for as it prints the whole line and not the characters one by one.

Comment: @MichaelRuth Can it maybe also be caused by empty lines? It looks like my string contains two of them.

Comment: No, a line which contains _only_ a newline, i.e. `"\n"` will produce a different error: `ValueError: not enough values to unpack`. Now if your "empty" lines contain spaces, e.g. `"            \n"` then yes, this could cause your error.

Comment: the second version seems to work fine for me, i can only reproduce the error with the first one

Comment: @MichaelRuth This was the mistake, I guess. I had a line that contained such characters and by removing it, the second version works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the trailing white space in the input, I'm guessing. Use `strip`

```
s = '''
06 6 452872995438985XXX
09 22 160462182344032XXX
11 17 302885091519234XXX
'''

lines = s.strip().split('\n')
tokens = [l.split(' ') for l in lines]
final = [f'{day}/{month} {misc}' for month, day, misc in tokens]

for f in final:
    print(f)
```